# What are Optimus primes?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I have been looking around the internet looking for the definition of an Optimus prime though I have not been successful. I appreciate any help with the search for the definition of these numbers.

Comment: Isn't that a Transformer?

Comment: @RSerrao yes although I was told that there is a set of primes named after Optimus Prime.

Comment: Google comes up with nothing. I've never heard of those.

Comment: That's why I'm hoping that someone here may know a definition.

Comment: This is an example of a bad decision in naming a class of objects. (Pro tip: before you name something in a published paper, Google your proposed name to ensure that your definition will not be buried among 10 million irrelevant "matching" pages.)

Comment: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-011-9959-8 ?

Comment: Why do you believe that's an actual thing?  (Serious q)

Comment: A prof told me that there is a set of primes with that name. I fully admit, that it is entirely possible that they were simply pulling my leg.

Comment: Thanks for the question. This is the first time I retracted the close vote. Still, I think it would've been better to add more context (such as the fact that your teacher told you about these primes) uless you want to risk people thinking it's a joke

Comment: I didn't intend for this question to be a joke. I figured that it was an actual mathematical term that was very difficult to find due it's name. There's a lot of random knowledge here and so I figured this was the best place to find a definition.

Comment: @DavidK: I agree it was a bad decision; incidentally, I doubt that it was an error of inattention (the authors did not fail to consider name collisions), but rather one of misapprehension (the authors failed to appreciate the effects of the name collision).

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, I expect it the name was a deliberate pun on a popular fictional character without consideration of the consequences. One need not actually Google this to see the problem, although my "10 million" was the result of my actual Google search, rounded down. The "pro tip" was meant to be more generally applicable, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [Optimus Prime](http://oeis.org/A217090) is any odd prime $p$ where $\left(1 + \sqrt{P_p(-1)\cdot p}\right)^p - 1 = a + b\cdot\sqrt{P_p(-1)\cdot p}$, where $\gcd(a, b) = p$ and $P_p(x)$ is the [Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) at $p$.

Example:

$\left(1 + \sqrt{7 \cdot \frac{1}{16}(-429 + 693 - 315 + 35)}\right)^7 - 1= (1 + \sqrt{7}i)^7 -1 = -833 + 448\cdot\sqrt{7}i$

Note: $\gcd(-833,448) = 7$.